# How is it possible to return multiline error messages in main?

Tags: rust

I would like to have a `main` function that can fail, return `Err(String)` and print it in case of failure.

I tried it like this:

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), String> {
    Err(String::from("Line1\nLine2"))
}
```

It works well with simple strings, but for multiline errors `\n` or `\r\n` is displayed instead of a line break.

How is it possible to correctly display line breaks?

Comment: If you want a specific output it's very likely you want to catch the error and do your own printing instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with the builtin printing, [as it always uses `Debug` formatting](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.67.0/src/std/process.rs.html#2211). But you can print your own. You can even have a little wrapper that forwards `Debug` to `Display`, having a convienet error handling (but it may break with types that are not the error type themselves but are convertible into it, which will work implicitly with the error type operator but requires an explicit conversion with `PrettyError`. However, if you keep `PrettyError` only in `main()` it should be good enough):

```rust
use std::fmt;

pub struct PrettyError<T>(pub T);

impl<T> From<T> for PrettyError<T> {
    fn from(v: T) -> Self {
        Self(v)
    }
}

impl<T: fmt::Display> fmt::Debug for PrettyError<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt::Display::fmt(&self.0, f)
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), PrettyError<String>> {
    Err(String::from("Line1\nLine2"))?;
    Ok(())
}
// Or
fn main() -> Result<(), PrettyError<String>> {
    Err(PrettyError(String::from("Line1\nLine2")))
}
```